# ncurses - output to a text file

Tags: c++, file, ncurses

I use the ncurses library. Is it possible to print output into a plain text file instead of a terminal?

I tried to use the newterm function (in C++). a.txt is the output file

```
#include <curses.h>
int main()
{   
    FILE * o = fopen("a.txt", "w");
    FILE * i = fopen("b.txt", "r");
    SCREEN * scr = newterm(NULL, o, i);

    set_term(scr);

    mvaddch(5, 5, '#'); 

    refresh();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

How shoud I edit the code/what function should I use so it works?

Comment: line plots and other things in ASCII art

Comment: Why do you think writing through ncurses is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: It's the only library I'm allowed to use at this moment. I can use C++ standard output input and ncurses.

Comment: And what about just writing out whatever you need?